# How to debug Azure Functions Core Tools with VS Code debugger?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm locally developing a Node.js app with  Azure Functions Core Tools. I would like to debug it with help of VS Code debugger, but I get this error:

```
Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: 
Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5858)
```

For debug option, I've chosen "Attach to JavaScript Functions". This option was there by default and I haven't created it.

Here is content of my launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
{
  "name": "Attach to JavaScript Functions",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "port": 5858,
  "preLaunchTask": "runFunctionsHost"
}
]}
```

How can I fix this issue and make the debugging to work?

Comment: Do you have the VS Code Azure Functions extension installed? Get it here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly issue was resolved by itself. So I close this issue.